# How can I enable specification extensions in asyncapi-react-component?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, asyncapi

I'm using the asyncapi react component to render asyncapi documents. (https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi-react)

In the asyncapi specification it is allowed to use extensions (x-... values) at certain schema objects. (E.g. the server object: https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/specifications/v2.0.0#serverObject)

Is it possible to show these custom extensions with asyncapi-react component? How can I enable these functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a maintainer of AsyncAPi-React component. For now, rendering extensions is only possible with the `next` version of the component - you can install it with:

```
npm i @asyncapi/react-component@next
```

Only extensions in the Channel, Operation and Message Objects are rendered, the rest is ignored. If you want to have extensions rendered in the right places, please create an issue https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi-react/issues :)

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. :)